# VB.NET Code to Change Excel 2007 Column Cell Format to Number no Decimal

Tags: vb.net, excel

VB.NET code to change Excel 2007 Column Cell Format from Text to a Number no Decimal.

Right now Column F shows values that look like
3E+13
3E+13

Manually changing it to a Number with No Decimal shows the correct value.
30000046605562
30000041582875

Of course I would like to automate this.

Comment: btw, hope we're talking about VBA?

Comment: Actually it was for the PL/B language but you would have scatched your head if I said that. Thanks again for your help. The following is the line of PL/B code used to select the column and set the format: SETPROP autXlSheet.Columns.Item("F"),*NumberFormat="0"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the rows (maybe programmatically) and perform

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
```

To select all cells in the sheet call

```
Cells.Select
```